# Encryption in C# and decryption in C (QNX OS)

Tags: c#, c++, c, encryption, qnx

I am trying to encrypt the message in C# platform using Security.Cryptography library. Please find the code below.

```
using (AuthenticatedAesCng aes = new AuthenticatedAesCng())
{
    byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);                   // Convert to bytes.
    aes.Key = getEncryptionKey();                                   // Retrieve Key.
    aes.IV = generateIV();                                          // Generate nonce.
    aes.CngMode = CngChainingMode.Gcm;                              // Set Cryptographic Mode.
    aes.AuthenticatedData = getAdditionalAuthenticationData();     // Set Authentication Data.
    byte[] encrypted;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (IAuthenticatedCryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateAuthenticatedEncryptor())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                // Write through and retrieve encrypted data.
                cs.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                byte[] cipherText = ms.ToArray();

                // Retrieve tag and create array to hold encrypted data.
                byte[] authenticationTag = encryptor.GetTag();
                encrypted = new byte[cipherText.Length + aes.IV.Length + authenticationTag.Length];

                // Set needed data in byte array.
                aes.IV.CopyTo(encrypted, 0);
                authenticationTag.CopyTo(encrypted, IV_LENGTH);
                cipherText.CopyTo(encrypted, IV_LENGTH + TAG_LENGTH);
            }
        }
    }  
} 

// Store encrypted value in base 64.
// Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

lock (SnmpUdpClient.Client)
{
    nRet = SnmpUdpClient.Client.Send(encrypted, idx, gaddr.IPEndPoint);
}
```

I am sending the encrypted packet to the client via UDP connection . Client should receive the encrypted data and decrypt it using C/C++ platform (QNX OS).

Can anyone Please help me to understand how to do it. Does C/C++ or QNX has some library which can be used to achieve the same.

Comment: Your `Send()` is in the wrong place, first close all your streams. Move it down a couple of `}`.

Comment: Done changes as suggested .

Comment: Edited it a little more. It's pseudo code now, you'd need to keep a reference to the memorystream for use outside of the usings.

Comment: I am able to send the encrypted packet to the client. I can see the packets at client side. I am facing difficulty in decrypting the packets. Client side code is written in C/C++. Can anyone suggest the decryption method to be used in client side. How we will be authenticating the packets being received.

Comment: Ok, but are they the correct length? Always verify.

Comment: Sure @HenkHolterman Thanks . Verified the packet received.